# ArrayList equality JUnit testing

Tags: java, junit

I want to use the `assertArrayEquals(ArrayList<Token>, ArrayList<Token>)` with these arguments (i.e. arrayList of tokens). But Java tells me I need to create such a method. Is there a way to test for the equality of two arrayLists of whatever type in Junit?

Comment: The normal `assertEquals` should work just fine for `ArrayList<Token>`.

Comment: @Bohemian: I don't believe that.  `List.equals` checks for element-by-element equality, and `assertEquals` uses the `equals` method.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> I want to use the `assertArrayEquals(ArrayList<Token>, ArrayList<Token>)` with these arguments (i.e. arrayList of tokens). But Java tells me I need to create such a method.

It's telling you that you need to create the method because there is no such method in the JUnit library. There isn't such a method in the JUnit library because `assertArrayEquals` is for comparing *arrays*, and and `ArrayList` is *not* an array—it's a `List`.

> Is there a way to test for the equality of two arrayLists of whatever type in Junit?

You can check the equality of two `ArrayLists` (really, any two `List` objects) using [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), so you should be able to use JUnit's `assertEquals` method and it will work just fine.

Comment: Does the `asserEquals` checks based on override `equals()` method?

Comment: @Ram - Yes, it will use the overridden equals implementation for Lists.

Answer (score 15):

What you probably want to use is `void org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals(Object[] expecteds, Object[] actuals)`. You just need to convert List to array with `toArray()` method, like that:

```
ArrayList<Token> list1 = buildListOne(); // retrieve or build list
ArrayList<Token> list2 = buildListTwo(); // retrieve or build other list with same items

assertArrayEquals(list1.toArray(), list2.toArray());
```

Don't forget to import this assert.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;
```

But this methods only works if items in both lists have same order. If the order is not guaranteed, then you need to sort the lists with `Collections.sort()` method, but your object need to implement `java.util.Comparable` interface with one method `int compareTo(T o)`.

PS: The other possible solution is to use assertEquals and wrap your list into Set, like that:

```
assertEquals(new HashSet<Token>(list1), new HashSet<Token>(list2));
```

Answer (score 7):

Imagine `myArraylist` is an array list with contents `"one", "two", "three"`

This works fine:

```
 List<String> categories = asList("one", "two", "three");
 assertTrue(myArraylist.equals(categories));
```

Dont forget to import: `import static java.util.Arrays.asList;`

Comment: Works, but does not give you insights where the differences are when the assertion fails.

Answer (score 6):

try

```
Assert.assertEquals(Object expected, Object actual);
```

it works fine with Collections

Answer (score 4):

You can override `equals` or `hashcode` method of Element type eg: `ArralyList<Element>`, `ArrayList<String>` - (either primitive data type or custom data element),  You can override the method, and compare all you data inside in that method and return `true`/`false` accordingly.

You can then directly use `assertEquals(arraylist1 , arraylist2)` for your junit test.

Below is sample Object Class

```java
public class Customer {
    String name;
    int age;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;

        // it checks if the argument is of the type Customer by comparing the classes
        // of the passed argument and this object.
        // if(!(obj instanceof Customer)) return false; ---> avoid.
        if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass())
            return false;

        // type casting of the argument.
        Customer customer = (Customer) obj;
        if (customer.getName().equals(this.name) &&
            (customer.getAge() == this.age))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Below is the sample class for Junit test :

```java
public class CustomerTest {

    @Test
    public void testCustomerMatch() {

        ArrayList<Customer> expectedCustomerListOutput; // add your data in this list
        ArrayList<Customer> actualCustomerListOutput; // add your data in this list

        //used the overridden equal method of trade objects
        assertEquals(expectedTradeOutput, actualTradeMatchList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using some off the shelf junit framework like unitils etc they have methods like assertReflectionEquals (similary other framework does) where you can any two objects using reflection . If you are not using any third party junit framework , you can write your own similar generic method

Comment: Guys Downvote is great but really its irritating when somebody downvote without giving any feedback its irritating .It does not give chance to  poster to improve on next time

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way: just simply add `@EqualsAndHashCode` on your Token class.
`@EqualsAndHashCode` is provided by Project Lombok and generates hashCode and equals implementations from the fields of your object.

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Token {
   private String abc;
   // ...
}
```

And the following assertion works well in JUnit  4.13.1

```
Assert.assertEquals(expectedArrayList, actualArrayList);
```

https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode