# assertion error while asserting arrayList contents in junit

Tags: java, junit4, hamcrest

```
 @Test
    public void testAchievementsSize(){
        Player player = getPlayer();
        List<Achievement> playerAchievements = achievementManager.checkForPlayerAchievements(preparePlayerStatistics(player));
        assertEquals(3,playerAchievements.size());
        assertThat(playerAchievements, containsInAnyOrder(new BruiserAward(),new SharpShooterAward(),new FastKillerAward()));

    }
```

causing the below error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: iterable over [<Bruiser>, <Sharp shooter>, <Fast Killer>] in any order
     but: Not matched: <Bruiser>

    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:956)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:923)
```

`Hashcode` and `equals` is overridden like below:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.getName().hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

if(obj != null &&  obj instanceof Achievement){
    Achievement achievement = (Achievement) obj;
    achievement.getName().equals(this.getName());
}
return false;
}
```

Have tried solutions [ArrayList equality JUnit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456910/arraylist-equality-junit-testing) present here using `assertTrue` and `assertArrayEquals` but no luck

Am I missing anything?

Update:

Tried below:

```
@Test
    public void testAchievementsSize(){
        Player player = getPlayer();
        List<Achievement> playerAchievements = achievementManager.checkForPlayerAchievements(preparePlayerStatistics(player));
        assertEquals(3,playerAchievements.size());
        assertArrayEquals(playerAchievements.toArray(new Achievement[playerAchievements.size()]),
                new Achievement[]{new BruiserAward(),new SharpShooterAward(),new FastKillerAward()} );

    }
```

causing error:

```
arrays first differed at element [0]; expected: com.techdisqus.achievement.BruiserAward<Bruiser> but was: com.techdisqus.achievement.BruiserAward<Bruiser>
Expected :com.techdisqus.achievement.BruiserAward<Bruiser> 
Actual   :com.techdisqus.achievement.BruiserAward<Bruiser>
```

and

```
   @Test
    public void testAchievementsSize(){
        Player player = getPlayer();
        List<Achievement> playerAchievements = achievementManager.checkForPlayerAchievements(preparePlayerStatistics(player));
        assertEquals(3,playerAchievements.size());
        assertArrayEquals(playerAchievements.toArray(),
                new Achievement[]{new BruiserAward(),new SharpShooterAward(),new FastKillerAward()} );

    }
```

causing

```
arrays first differed at element [0]; expected: com.techdisqus.achievement.BruiserAward<Bruiser> but was: com.techdisqus.achievement.BruiserAward<Bruiser>
Expected :com.techdisqus.achievement.BruiserAward<Bruiser> 
Actual   :com.techdisqus.achievement.BruiserAward<Bruiser>
```

Comment: Can you show us `checkForPlayerAchievements` method code?

Comment: The deleted answer seems correct.  Check the equals method of the BruserAward class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is often the case,
the answer is ***Pay attention to the code you write***.

Look at the equals method you included in your question.
Answer this question: What value is returned when this is true `obj != null &&  obj instanceof Achievement`.

Once you answer that question,
fix the problem.

Comment: Silly me, this miss cost me few hours.. but thank you for showing it to me.